# LIBGDX problem , I don't have box2d "Body" class

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx, box2d

I installed libgdx for android studio and i don't have "Body" class in "com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d". I have been using earlier libgdx and box2d on Eclipse (Desktop app) and i didn't have any problems. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you [injected](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#box2d-gradle) dependency of `box2d` by gradle in your required module

Comment: Yes , dependencies looks okay, i think. I have every box2d class except "Body" this is a problem.

Comment: Please add the version number of your dependencies